# Best Practice: r.PostFormValue("key") VS r.PostForm.Get("key")

Tags: forms, http, go

When I looked at examples how to read form data, I came across two ways to read a post forms value:

Using `r.PostFormValue()`

```
username := r.PostFormValue("username")
password := r.PostFormValue("password")
```

Using `r.PostForm.Get()`

```
username := r.PostForm.Get("username")
password := r.PostForm.Get("password")
```

Why use one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [`Request.PostFormValue()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.PostFormValue) and [`Request.PostForm.Get()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#Values.Get) return the same value, the main difference is that `Request.PostForm` is not populated automatically.

`Request.PostForm` is a map of form data, which is populated by calling [`Request.ParseMultipartForm()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseMultipartForm) or [`Request.ParseForm()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseForm). This doesn't happen automatically, because this requires reading and parsing the request body, and this may not be wanted in all cases.

`Request.PostFormValue()` calls `ParseMultipartForm()` and `ParseForm()` if necessary (if it hasn't been called prior) to ensure `Request.PostForm` is populated. `Request.PostForm` is a [selector](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Selectors) denoting the `Request`'s `PostForm` field, and as such, it does not involve calling `ParseForm()`. It *assumes* you've already done that. If you haven't, any `PostForm.Get()` calls will "silently" return an empty string.

So you should only use `Request.PostForm.Get()` if you've already parsed the form data (e.g. by explicitly calling `Request.ParseForm()` or indirectly via a prior `Request.PostFormValue()` call).